# Perl code to return the source folder does not work

Tags: file, perl

The perl script (name: perl1.pl) looks for any *.obj files in the current folder (the folder where the perl script resides) and operates on those files. The problem is that the code to retrieve the current folder is generating an error. The $SourceFolder is defined in line 72 and the error shows when the $SourceFolder variable is used in line 86. Please help me troubleshoot it.

I start the program as follows: `Perl perl1.pl -r 500 -M 10 -s 1` (setting some initial values)

(NOTE: when asked for source and destination folders I press return, allowing the script to use the current folder)

The error I get is as follows:

> open Source folder failed! at perl1.pl line 86,  line 2.

It appears to be that maybe the full path is not included in "__FILE_".

Thanks for any help.

The relevant code

```
print "\Source Folder:";
$SourceFolder=<STDIN>;
chop($SourceFolder);
if (length($SourceFolder)==0) {
    $temp=__FILE__;
    $SourceFolder=substr($temp,0,rindex($temp,"\\")); 
}
```

The entire program below

```
use constant PI => 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;

# @AllFiles store all file types in the SourceFolder
@AllFiles,@SourceFiles,@TempSourceFiles,@DestinationFiles;
$i,$OBJFilesCount,$ValueLineCount,$CoverExistFile,$ConversionCount;
@ValueArray,$LineData,@LineValue;
$SourceFolder,$DestinationFolder; 

# The following variables are used to calculate during the conversion
$La,$Lo,$a;
$R,$e,$m,$n,$Alpha,$Beta;
$r,$M,$s;
$X2,@Xs,@Zs,@Ys,@Xd,@Yd,@Zd;
#
# main program
#
# call the help subprogram.
#
&Show_help;
#
# call the read paramter subprogram
#
&Read_parameter;
#
# call the seek SourceFiles subprogram
#
&Seek_SourceFiles;      
$ConversionCount=0;
for ($i=0;$i<$OBJFilesCount;$i++) {
    #
    # call the read SourceFiles subprogram
    # call the create destination filenames subprogram
    #
    &Read_SourceFiles;                             
    &Create_DestinationFiles;  
} 
print "\nThere are $ConversionCount files translated successfully!\n";

#help subprogram
sub Show_help {                        
    if ((lc(@ARGV[0]) eq "-h") or (lc(@ARGV[0]) eq "-help")) {
        open (PATH,"help.hlp") || die ("open help.hlp failed!");        
        while ($LineData=<PATH>) {
            print "$LineData";
        }
        close (PATH);
        exit();
    }
}

# read parameter subprogram
sub Read_parameter {
    # if the pamameter is wrong, Error.
    if ((lc(@ARGV[0]) ne "-r") or (uc(@ARGV[2]) ne "-M") or (lc(@ARGV[4]) ne "-s")) {
        &Parameter_error;                                   
        exit();                  
    }
    # if r,M,s is not a int, Error.
    #  
    if ((@ARGV[1] =~/[a-z]/i) or (@ARGV[1] =~/[!@#""''^&*(){}~_+=-|\/?><,:;]/) or (@ARGV[3] =~/[a-z]/i) or (@ARGV[3] =~/[!@#""''^&*(){}~_+=-|\/?><,:;]/) or (@ARGV[5] =~/[a-z]/i)or (@ARGV[5] =~/[!@#""''^&*(){}~_+=-|\/?><,:;]/) ) {              
        &Parameter_error; 
        exit();
    }                                              
    $r="@ARGV[1]";
    $M="@ARGV[3]";
    $s="@ARGV[5]";
    print "\Source Folder:";
    $SourceFolder=<STDIN>;
    chop($SourceFolder);
    if (length($SourceFolder)==0) {
        $temp=__FILE__;
        $SourceFolder=substr($temp,0,rindex($temp,"\\")); 
    }

    print "Destination Folder:";
    $DestinationFolder=<STDIN>;
    chop($DestinationFolder);
    if (length($DestinationFolder)==0) {
        $temp=__FILE__;
        $DestinationFolder=substr($temp,0,rindex($temp,"\\")); 
    }
}

# Seek SourceFiles
sub Seek_SourceFiles {
    opendir(dirvar,$SourceFolder) || die ("\nopen Source folder failed!");
    #put all of the filenames and subdirectories under the source folder into a ValueArray
    @AllFiles=readdir(dirvar);                 
    closedir(dirvar);
    #Look for *.obj files
    @TempSourceFiles=grep(/.obj/,@AllFiles);   
    #Total numbers of *.obj
    $OBJFilesCount= grep(/.obj/,@AllFiles); 
    #Get all valid obj files.
    $ValidOBJFilesCount=0;
    for ($i=0;$i<$OBJFilesCount;$i++) {
        # Get all of the .obj files in the SourceFolder.
        @temp=split(/ /,"@TempSourceFiles[$i]");
        $Length=@temp;
        #Check the OBJ file valid.
        if($Length==8){
            @SourceFiles[$ValidOBJFilesCount]=@TempSourceFiles[$i];
            $ValidOBJFilesCount++;
        }                          
    }
    $OBJFilesCount=$ValidOBJFilesCount;
    if ($OBJFilesCount==0) {
        print "\bThere are no valid .obj files exist!\b";
        exit();
    }
}

#Get SourceFiles information
sub Read_SourceFiles{
    local @num;
    @ValueArray = split(/ /, @SourceFiles[$i]);
    @num[0]=substr(@ValueArray[1],0,length(@ValueArray[1])-6);
    @num[1]=substr(@ValueArray[1],length(@num[0])+1,2);
    @num[2]=substr(@ValueArray[1],length(@ValueArray[1])-2,2);
    @num[3]=substr(@ValueArray[4],0,length(@ValueArray[4])-6);
    @num[4]=substr(@ValueArray[4],length(@num[3])+1,2);
    @num[5]=substr(@ValueArray[4],length(@ValueArray[4])-2,2);
    #Judge La is a positive or negative number 
    if (substr(@num[0],0,1) eq "-") {
        $La=@num[0]-@num[1]/60-@num[2]/3600;
    }                                            
    else {
        $La=@num[0]+@num[1]/60+@num[2]/3600;
    }
    #Judge Lo is a positive or negative number
    if (substr(@num[3],0,1) eq "-") {   
        $Lo=@num[3]-@num[4]/60-@num[5]/3600;
    }
    else {
        $Lo=@num[3]+@num[4]/60+@num[5]/3600;
    }
    $a=$ValueArray[7]/3600;
    #above change the degrees, minutes and seconds to decimal
    $ValueLineCount=0;
    open (path,"$SourceFolder//@SourceFiles[$i]") || die ("\nopen path failed!\n");
    while ($LineData=<path>) {
        @LineValue=split(/ /,"$LineData");
        #Look for the Values in the file.
        if (index("$LineData","v ")==0) {             
            $ValueLineCount++;
            if ($ValueLineCount==2) {
                #Get the first numeric value in the 2nd ValueLineCount 
                $X2=$LineValue[1];
            }
        }
    }
    close(path);
    #print "\n"; 
}

# Create the destination files
sub Create_DestinationFiles {
    if ($i==0) {
        print "\nTranslation is Processing,please wait......\n";
    }
    open (path,"$SourceFolder//@SourceFiles[$i]") || die ("open path failed!");
    $ValueLineCount=0;
    #Create the destination filename
    @DestinationFiles[$i]=substr (@SourceFiles[$i],0, length(@SourceFiles[$i])-4)." r$r M$M s$s s3.0.0.obj";     
    # Estimate should the program Cover all of the existing destination files.
    if ($CoverExistFile ne "A") {
        # Estimate if the Destination file exists or not.
        if (-e "$DestinationFolder//@DestinationFiles[$i]") {
            print STDERR ("\n@DestinationFiles[$i] exists, do you want to Cover it?[Y/N/All/Quit]");
            $CoverExistFile=<STDIN>;
            chop($CoverExistFile);
            # Cover this Destination file
            if (uc($CoverExistFile) eq "Y") {
                open (PATH,">$DestinationFolder//$DestinationFiles[$i]") || die ("open PATH failed!");
            } 
            # Do not CoverExistFile this Destination file.
            if (uc($CoverExistFile) eq "N") {
                return;
            } 
            # Cover all of the existing Destination files
            if ((uc($CoverExistFile) eq "A") or (uc($CoverExistFile) eq "ALL")) {
                $CoverExistFile="A";                         
                open (PATH,">$DestinationFolder//$DestinationFiles[$i]") || die ("open PATH failed!");
            }
            # Quit the program.
            if ((uc($CoverExistFile) eq "Q") or (uc($CoverExistFile) eq "QUIT")) {
                print "\nThere are $ConversionCount Files Converted Successfully!\n";
                exit();                            
            }
        }
        else {
            open (PATH,">>$DestinationFolder//$DestinationFiles[$i]") || die ("open PATH failed!");
        }
    }
    else {
        open (PATH,">$DestinationFolder//$DestinationFiles[$i]") || die ("open PATH failed!");
    }
    # Find the details of source file and calculate the values
    $ConversionCount++;
    while ($LineData=<path>) {
        @LineValue=split(/ /,"$LineData");
        if (index("$LineData","# object ")==0) {
            print PATH ("# Converted by Utility Version 3.0.0\n");
            print PATH ("# comment\n");
        }
        if (index("$LineData","v ")==0) {
            $ValueLineCount++;
            @Xs[ValueLineCount]=$LineValue[1];
            @Zs[ValueLineCount]=$LineValue[2];
            @Ys[ValueLineCount]=$LineValue[3];
            $n=sprintf("%.0f",(@Ys[ValueLineCount]/$X2));
            $m=sprintf("%.0f",(@Xs[ValueLineCount]/$X2));
            $Alpha=$La-$n*$a;
            $Beta=$Lo+$m*$a;
            if (@Zs[ValueLineCount]==0) {
                $e=0;
                $s=0;
            }
            else {
                $e=$Zs[ValueLineCount]*$M;
            }
            $R=$s+$r*(1+$e/6370997);
            @Xd[ValueLineCount]=$R*cos($Alpha*PI/180)*sin($Beta*PI/180);
            @Yd[ValueLineCount]=-$R*cos($Alpha*PI/180)*cos($Beta*PI/180);
            @Zd[ValueLineCount]=$R*sin($Alpha*PI/180);
            # Output the calculated values to the destination files and hold 8 decimal places 
            print PATH ("v ");
            printf PATH ("%.8f ",@Xd[ValueLineCount]);
            printf PATH ("%.8f ",@Yd[ValueLineCount]);
            printf PATH ("%.8f",@Zd[ValueLineCount]);
            print PATH ("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            # Output unchanged data to the destination file.
            print PATH ("@LineValue");          
        }   
    }
    close(PATH);
    close(path);
    print "Translate File:@DestinationFiles[$i] completed!\n";
}

# Parameter Error Subprogram
sub Parameter_error {
    print "\nVersion 3.0.0\n";
    print "Use for ActiveState (R) Active Perl Version 5.6.0\n";
    print "Copyright (C) 2000-2019.\n";
    print "\nInput Parameter Error,Please use Command (Translating.pl -h)\nto get help information!\n";
}
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: "_It appears to be that maybe the full path is not included in `__FILE__`_"  -- well, try?  (It indeed isn't, and even if it were on some builds or systems it is definitely not guaranteed).  Either way, that wouldn't be the right way (what you could do using `Cwd::abs_path(__FILE__)` even though even that doesn't _guarantee_ it), but we have `FindBin` for it.

Comment: `Cwd::abs_path(__FILE__)` is clearer and more reliable than FindBin.

Comment: @Grinnz Wow, can you elaborate on _that_?  (For one it doesn't, in fact, guarantee that you get the full path.  Then ... what is "_unreliable_" with `FindBin`?).  That "clear" part is entirely personal here -- you left out the fact that I'd also need `File::Basename::dirname` or such then

Comment: @zdim I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't guarantee that you get the full path", as that's exactly what abs_path does. I was referring to it being clearer in functionality, not readability - can you say off the top of your head what FindBin will do if you have a script require another script? If FindBin is loaded at runtime? There is never any doubt what `__FILE__` refers to.

Comment: @zdim More reliable is referring to the fact that FindBin could return executables from your `PATH` before Perl 5.16, and you can't update it from CPAN to fix that.

Comment: @Grinnz "_FindBin could return_"  -- these are known edge cases from versions that are pushing it on the decade old.  While you aren't talking about a bag of quirks from all of Unix, some murky and well hidden, that may come through `dirname`?  I appreciate preferences but that's what they are; shouldn't be made into general recommendations.  (As for `abs_path`, I've seen it return `.` -- again, in special cases, and I didn't dog it, but ...)

Comment: @Grinnz, FindBin and `dirname(abs_path($0))` will reliably be relative to the script (unless you change `$0`). `dirname(abs_path(__FILE__))` will reliably be relative to the current file. Neither is better or more reliable; they serve different purposes.

Comment: @zdim There are no edge cases from dirname. The caveat is simply that you get the parent directory even if called on a directory.

Comment: @zdim I have never heard of that abs_path bug, can you point to a bug report?

Comment: @zdim, Your point is moot because FindBin uses `abs_path` too. The difference is `$0` vs `__FILE__`.

Comment: `abs_path` would fail if insufficient permissions are available. It returns `undef` on error, though, not `.`

Comment: @ikegami "_FindBin uses abs_path too._" -- fair enough, my point really was that `FindBin` is no less reliable. As for `abs_path`, perhaps I can reconstitute the circumstances under which I was getting `.` (had to change the way) but can't do that readily (so maybe I shouldn't have mentioned)

Comment: @ikegami I disagree that there is no difference in reliability, because caveats exist for $0 and additional caveats exist for FindBin, but they don't apply to `__FILE__`. @zdim You probably are thinking of what happens if you call `dirname` on the undef you might get from `abs_path`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and also to @zdim . I am not a coder and barely understand the code in my own program (it was written for me over 10 years ago) and, by the way, it worked fine on whatever computers I was using then, though the code has not changed since. Sorry to be so ignorant but could you kindly indicate the exact change you are suggesting. Could you please tell me what to add and what to substitute in my code. Thanks again

Comment: @Grinnz, By that logic, `__FILE__` is also unreliable. So take your pick. Either both are unreliable, or both are reliable at what they do.

Comment: @ikegami It is not. The only way `__FILE__` can be changed is with a parser hint, not at runtime. `$0` is changed commonly for legitimate reasons.

Comment: @Grinnz, `__FILE__` can be changed as easily as `$0`. (`#line 1 x.pl`)

Comment: @Grinnz, But again, that's all moot. There's no point in comparing things with different purposes. `$0` and `__FILE__` are not interchangeable.

Comment: @ikegami You are equivocating very different things. The parser hint can't be applied at a distance by calling a function. And yes they are very different purposes. The vast majority of use cases for this are relative to a file you control, therefore the more reliable `__FILE__` is usable.

Answer (score 2):

Getting full paths to the script is the purpose of the core [FindBin](https://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) module

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use FindBin qw($RealBin);

say $RealBin;
```

Please do review the docs carefully for a possible subtlety in a particular use case.

*Always* start your programs with `use warnings;` and `use strict;`.

---

There is also the older, "tried and true" way

```
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use File::Basename qw(dirname);

say dirname( abs_path($0) );
```

where I've used [`$0` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) instead of the [special literal `__FILE__`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors).  If subtleties matter in your use please compare carefully since they're slightly different.

While this has been commonly used for the longest time note from [File::Basename](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) docs

> - **dirname**
>     This function is provided for compatibility with the Unix shell command `dirname(1)` and has inherited some of its quirks. In spite of its name it does **NOT** always return the directory name as you might expect. To be safe, if you want the directory name of a path use `fileparse()`.

(original emphasis)     So things could get a little complicated.

---

Then there are yet other modules for working with the filesystem to be found on CPAN.  I find it easy to recommend a very useful [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny), with which we can do for this job

```
use Path::Tiny;

say path($0)->realpath->parent;
```

(I find that the order `parent->realpath` works fine as well)

As docs say this is a "*more expensive*" option than the `absolute` method, but that one won't resolve `'d1/../d2'` into canonical paths unless `File::Spec` does on that platform.

Comment: That caveat for dirname cannot apply to `__FILE__` since it will always be a file in a directory (at least, if we're talking about a source file). `$0` on the other hand may be set to anything to change how it appears in `ps` so is unreliable.

Comment: +1 to the Path::Tiny recommendation - though Dir::Self is a more direct implementation of this if we're going to CPAN.

Comment: @Grinnz Well, they're different; `__FILE__` is a compilation unit (source), `$0` the running thing; call them out of a module and we'll have to make decisions.  I don't know what they (really) want, but `dirname` isn't excused on this account.

Comment: @Grinnz See, the `Path::Tiny` for instance -- I like it and am not shy to recommend it ... but I've got complaints as well.  I'm afraid it's a _very_ short list of things that come with no issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answers also @Grinnz. I possibly should have mentioned that I am not a coder and barely understand the code in my own program (it was written for me over 10 years ago) and, by the way, it worked fine on whatever computers I was using then, though the code has not changed since. Sorry to be so ignorant but could you kindly indicate the exact change you are suggesting. It looks as though I need not just to add but also to substitute code and I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

Comment: @waterrider  In the "_relevant code_" you show `$temp=__FILE__`; and then `$SourceFolder=substr($temp,0,rindex($temp,"\\"));`.  With this you use `__FILE__` to extract the folder where the script it (if the user doesn't supply that). But, as you thought, the `__FILE__` doesn't have the full path so that doesn't work.  Instead, you can remove these two statements (that I show above, in this comment), and have `use FindBin qw($RealBin);` at the beginning of the program and the `$RealBin` is the path to the folder where the script is (so, your `$sourceFolder`)